# How to keep menu toggle state after page reload

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

**Explanation**

I am new to .NET Blazor.

What I want to do is to use the default toggle button in .NET Blazor, and store its value somewhere.

Then if I choose that this menu has to be hidden, on page refresh, it stays hidden; otherwise it stays open.

**Question**

How can this be done correctly?

This is what I have done so far:

`MainLayout.Razor`:

```
 <button onclick="Toggle();">
 Toggle
 </button>
```

The code:

```
@code {
    public static bool _menuOpen = true;

    void Toggle()
    {
        _menuOpen = !_menuOpen;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out. You have to store the information somewhere.

Best is to store it in local storage, which you access through js function:

```
<div>
    <button @onclick="ChangeMenuState">Menu open/close</button>
    Menu is: @_menuOpen
</div>

@code{
    bool _menuOpen;
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            try
            {
                _menuOpen = bool.Parse(await Js.InvokeAsync<string>("localStorage.getItem", nameof(_menuOpen)));
                StateHasChanged();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"local storage not set for {_menuOpen}");
            }
        }
    }

    async Task ChangeMenuState()
    {
        _menuOpen = !_menuOpen;
        await Js.InvokeVoidAsync("localStorage.setItem", nameof(_menuOpen), _menuOpen);
    }

}
```